# Having trouble with cropper.js

Tags: javascript, web, crop

I am using [cropper.js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) on something I am working on, but having a little trouble getting it to work properly, is it possible to see what I might be doing wrong.

The image "duplicates" on the web page. (using a random image for example here)

My Html, Image:

```
<img id="ImageFrame" src="http://www.availstaffing.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Temporary-Button.jpg" style="max-width:100%" />
```

My javascript:

```
$(function () {
                var image = $('#ImageFrame');
                var cropImage = new Cropper(image[0], {
                    preview: 'div#CropPreview',
                    built: function () {},
                    crop: function (e) {
                        $("#cropX").val(Math.round(e.detail.x).toString());
                        $("#cropY").val(Math.round(e.detail.y).toString());
                        $("#cropH").val(Math.round(e.detail.height).toString());
                        $("#cropW").val(Math.round(e.detail.width).toString());
                    }
                });
            });
```

Then the result:
[image: Image is duplicating when the cropper renders]

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: try using : background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: I have found the problem. I forgot to add cropper.css to the page.

Comment: Hi,
Could you please mention what is #cropX,#cropY,#cropW,#cropH

Comment: They are hidden inputs `<input type="hidden" id="cropX" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try including **cropper.css** to your file